# Don't understand the step in Deriving quadratic equation

Tags: quadratics

[image]

It's from the book essenstial mathematics for computer graphics fast. I don't understand why after factorize the left side will become step 4. Can anyone explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment due to less reputation. Here is a hint
$$ (a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$
Also here is a proof I like using the relationship between the zeros of a polynomial and its constant coefficients.
This relationship is for a quadratic polynomial, $ax^2 + bx + c$ with zeroes $\alpha$ and $\beta$,
$$ \alpha\beta= \frac {c}{a}$$
$$ \alpha + \beta =\frac {-b}{a}$$
Using this,
\begin{align*} (\alpha - \beta)^2 &= (\alpha + \beta)^2 - 4\alpha\beta\\
 (\alpha - \beta)^2 &= \left(\frac {-b}{a}\right)^2 -\frac{4c}{a}\\
     \alpha - \beta &= \frac {\pm\sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{a} \end{align*}
Using this and $\alpha + \beta = \frac {-b}{a}$ , one can easily derive the quadratic formula